# python pandas read_csv boolean as string

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

The question is simple, though I can't find the solution after hours of searching.

I want to read a csv file, force objects and boolean to string, and write it to SQL. All of it works, however, when parsing the data to MSSQL, it converts boolean to the strings '0' and '1', rather than 'TRUE' and 'FALSE'.

See code below:

```
pandasDF = pandas.read_csv(pathCSV, sep = ';')
emptyTable(session, tableName)
obj_cols = pandasDF.select_dtypes(include=[object, bool]).columns.values.tolist()
pandasDF.to_sql(tableName, engine, if_exists = 'append', dtype = {c: String for c in obj_cols}, index = False)
```

I think the best solution would be to let pandas.read_csv stop recognizing boolean data types, however I can't find how to achieve this...

Comment: What is `String` in `dtype = {c: String for c in obj_cols}`? I ask because `String` with a capital S is not defined anywhere in your code.

Comment: It seems to me that all you need is to pass a custom dict to th e`dtype` argument in `to_sql`, as your '`String`' conversion is not working for boolean values.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses! The `dtype = {c: String for c in obj_cols}` works fine, it makes sure both object and boolean types are converted to strings (and it does so). Hence, the boolean columns are converted to strings, but in the format '1' and '0' rather than 'TRUE' and 'FALSE'

Comment: My point is you are importing the definition of String from somewhere not shown in your code.

Answer (score 0):

**`BOOL/BOOLEAN` are synonyms for `TINYINT(1)` in MySQL**.

The actual values `TRUE` and `FALSE` are aliases for `1` and `0`, see this example:

```
mysql> SELECT IF(0 = FALSE, 'true', 'false');
+--------------------------------+
| IF(0 = FALSE, 'true', 'false') |
+--------------------------------+
| true                           |
+--------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT IF(1 = TRUE, 'true', 'false');
+-------------------------------+
| IF(1 = TRUE, 'true', 'false') |
+-------------------------------+
| true                          |
+-------------------------------+
```

See [MySQL reference 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html) for more details.

Comment: If your target DBMS is MySQL, then your generated SQL queries should be fine. Have you tried to execute the queries?

Comment: The DBMS is MSSQL. I need varchars as date types in SQL (visualisation reasons later in the process), denoted as 'TRUE' and 'FALSE' rather than '1' and '0'. It should be possible I guess, right? Is it possible to read a csv, with the option not to recognize booleans?

Comment: Then maybe consider using `select if(...)` in your further process to get the values as the strings 'TRUE' and 'FALSE' for the visualization?